# #1932 - Table 'xxx.xxxx' doesn't exist in engine, change php mysql xampp version

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

i had uninstalled my old xampp before taking the backup the whole xampp.

After this i have installed my latest version of xampp in which php 7 is available. I think my old version is 5.6.8.

Then i have copy paste my database from

> "xampp\mysql\data\lms"

to my installed new xampp.

When i opened my database is showing an error.

> #1932 - Table 'xxx.xxxx' doesn't exist in engine.

[image]

I have googled a lot, but can't find my required answer. Please help my to come out this problem if any solution is.

Every Type of Help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this same issue after I copied database from xampp\mysql\data. Then I had to go to localhost:8080/phpmyadmin to export database, then import that database. In my opinion, copying database from folder will not work properly instead of exporting database from web page.

Comment: Export/import what?

Comment: I mean export database and then import it back to where you need, do not copy from the folder.

Comment: why get down to voting?
+1 for same issue.
I solved this problem by deleting the database and creating a new database and then importing the old database. it works.